# Problemas con lectura de Códigos QR

Tags: c#, system.io

Tengo unos lectores QR conectados a un pc en el cual tenemos una aplicación creada en visual studio en c#. Para la lectura de estos lectores usamos System.IO y el metodo READEXISTING(). El problema que tenemos es que cuando hemos leído varios códigos, nos encontramos con que el ultimo código leido nos aparece con caracteres extraños.
Por ejemplo: Código bueno -  8425561010039  Código malo - 842556101003/

```
                SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                indataEnv = sp.ReadExisting()
```

Esto seria como tenemos el código.

Gracias.

Comment: Habéis probado a usar [DataReceived](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) en lugar de leer por polling? Es posible que lo que os pase que que como haceis un Sleep de 100 ms, cuando leais los datos todavia no se hayan recibido todos por el puerto serie...